Cheap file server for 2 @ 16tB drives
I would like to replace a failing Windows desktop that I use for backups. It has 2 @ 16tB drives attached and I backup over WiFi.
I am looking for a cheap NAS alternative. Would a raspberry Pi 5 do the job? I see lots of articles about using the Pi as a file server, but nothing above 2tB. Is there something cheaper, or better in the same price bracket (no more than twice the price of the Pi)?

That's cause the rpi has no sata ports. Before I built my current NAS - I was running my large drives with a mini PC I already owned with one of these docks. With a 16TB disk power is going to be an issue so with a SBC, you're probably going to need to ensure your PC is powered.

Couple of options here, though with different levels of moving parts. TYou'd need a dock - I like this one from Orico. I've tested it with 14tb drives and it'll work with up to 20. However, unlike a 'proper' case, the disks are a little loud, especially compared to my NAS.
The Pi 5 is between  50-80 USD but lacks sata ports. I'm not really a fan of them, for all sorts of reasons. My temporary set up was a mini PC - keeping with the theme, its also an aliexpress purchase, and its a Celeron N3350. The MLLSE M2's not very powerful - its good enough to run a NAS, and has a windows licence (I installed linux anyway). I spent a bit to add a SSD rather than the EMMC it had (the pi lacks the support for both out of the box), a it has a case (Pi has it extra) and arguably it has better connectivity. You may find it somewhat cheaper elsewhere or choose to downgrade or upgrade to a cheaper or better machine, since this setup will work on any host that's got a USB 3.0 port.
Total cost's ~ 120 SGD/90USD. As long as you do your research - you can get another 2 bay dock, or host system

Thansk for that. I wish thet I had read this earlier & known about that mini-PC. As it is, I impluse bought yet another Pi
